# Guardar más de un registro en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo un formulario con los siguientes campos

- Nombre
- Apellido paterno y materno
- Edad
- Sexo
- Estatura
- Peso

La situación es que "estatura y peso" se guardan en una tabla y el resto de campos en otra independiente.

Y bien a modo de ejemplo:
Cuando dos usuarios utilizan este formulario mi función en el controlador guarda los dos registros correspondientes, sin embargo en la tabla "info_medicas" donde se guarda "estatura y peso" en el campo "id" de la persona me registra únicamente el primer "id"

Registros en mi tabla de personas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Registros en mi tabla de info medicas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo esta es la función que utilizo para guardar dichos registros

```
public function guardar_activacion(Request $request){
    activacion_participantes::create([
        'nombre' => $request['nombre'],
        'appaterno' => $request['appaterno'],
        'apmaterno' => $request['apmaterno'],
        'edad' => $request['edad'],
        'sexo' => $request['sexo'],
        'id_municipio' => $request['id_municipio'],
        'id_evento' => $request['id_evento']
    ]);

    info_medicas::create([
        'estatura' => $request['estatura'],
        'peso' => $request['peso'],
        'id_part_activ' => $request['id_part_activ']
    ]);

    return redirect("participante-activacion")->with('status','ATENCIÓN: El registro se insertó exitosamente');
}
```

Modelo activacion_participantes

```
class activacion_participantes extends Model
{
     use SoftDeletes;
     protected $primaryKey = 'id_part_activ';
     protected $fillable = ['id_part_activ','nombre','appaterno','apmaterno','edad','sexo','id_municipio','id_evento'];
     protected $date = ['deleted_at'];

     public function infos(){
          return $this->belongsTo('App\info_medicas','id_part_activ');
     }
}
```

Modelo info_medicas

```
class info_medicas extends Model
{
     use SoftDeletes;
     protected $primaryKey = 'id_info_medica';
     protected $fillable = ['id_info_medica','estatura','peso','medida_cintura','medida_cadera','medida_brazo','medida_muslo','medida_pantorrilla','avance','id_part_activ'];
     protected $date = ['deleted_at'];

     public function participantes(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\activacion_participantes','id_part_activ');
     }
}
```

Espero alguien logre ayudarme, se los agradecería

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo de tus modelos?

Comment: Listo ya he agregado los modelos @Dohko19

Comment: haz pensado en hacer una tabla polimorfica para este caso?

Comment: definiste ambas relaciones como `belongsTo`. Una de ellas, `infos` supongo, debería ser `hasOne` o `hasMany`, dependiendo si cada `activacion_participantes` puede tener uno o varios `info_medicas` relacionados

Comment: Solo cambie el belongsTo por el hasOne y bueno al parecer me ha funcionado, realizare pruebas para verificarlo, pero de momento gracias @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definiste ambas relaciones como `belongsTo`. Una de ellas, infos supongo, debería ser `hasOne` o `hasMany`, dependiendo si cada `activacion_participantes` puede tener uno o varios `info_medicas` relacionados.

Modelo **activacion_participantes**

```
class activacion_participantes extends Model
{
     public function infos(){
          return $this->hasOne('App\info_medicas','id_part_activ');
     }
}
```

Modelo **info_medicas**

```
class info_medicas extends Model
{
     public function participantes(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\activacion_participantes','id_part_activ');
     }
}
```

Luego en tu función **guardar_activacion**, puedes crear el registro para `activacion_participantes` y usar la relación definida para crear el registro de `info_medicas` relacionado:

```
public function guardar_activacion(Request $request){
    $activacion_participantes = activacion_participantes::create([
        'nombre' => $request['nombre'],
        'appaterno' => $request['appaterno'],
        'apmaterno' => $request['apmaterno'],
        'edad' => $request['edad'],
        'sexo' => $request['sexo'],
        'id_municipio' => $request['id_municipio'],
        'id_evento' => $request['id_evento']
    ])
    // aquí, como el método activacion_participantes::create() va a devolver la instancia del modelo que acabas de crear, puedes usar la relación infos() para crear el registro de info_medicas relacionado
    $activacion_participantes->infos()->create([ 
        'estatura' => $request['estatura'],
        'peso' => $request['peso'],
    ]);

    return redirect("participante-activacion")->with('status','ATENCIÓN: El registro se insertó exitosamente');
}
```

NOTA: Al no estar usando las [Convenciones de Modelo Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), deberás agregar manualmente el nombre de las tablas a los modelos con `protected $table = 'el_nombre_de_la_tabla';`, y posiblemente además de las llaves foráneas, también las llaves locales para las relaciones `$this->hasOne('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`.